# How to enable gender dependent salutation in phplist?

Tags: email, newsletter, phplist

I would like to know who to enable/implement in phplist a sex-dependend salutation.

Eg. "Dear Mr. Michael Meyers" or "Dear Mrs. Eva Evangelista" depending on the "gender".

Did not find any possibility to do this.

Comment: Should you really be assuming that everyone would like to be categorised as either a Mr. or a Mrs?

Comment: Simply yes, but i understand your idea behind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no such feature in PHPList per se.
But what you can do is add a new PHPList attribute called "salutation".
New subscribers will fill it up in the registration form.
For old subscribers, export the list to a spreadsheet, and add Mr. or Mrs. in each row*.
Finally, import the spreadsheet back to PHPList.

* An easier way to accomplish it is add a temporary column and write just 1 in it if the person is, for example, male.
Then in the real column do something like:

```
if(d2="1", "Mr.", "Mrs.")
```

Before you save it as CSV make sure to convert the real column from formulas into values, and delete the temporary column.